# Is there a function where if you modify a certain cell, the contents of another cell in the same column will be cleared?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

E.g. If the range of cells is A1:A20 and the independent variable is A5.
If A5 is modified then the content of A1 to A20 except for A5 will be cleared.

Comment: Have you googled anything.

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). See [How do I ask a good question?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Hi and welcome. _Is there a function_ A built-in function will not clear the contents of a cell/range. The answer by @doubleunary is a script, and that's your only option to physically delete the contents of cell. If that's not what you wanted/expected, then you need to provide more information in your question.

Comment: As the asker, you have a special privilege when a good answer is given to your question. You can [accept the answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) that you believe is the best solution to your problem. "Accepting" an answer is a way of acknowledging the work of the volunteer as well as helping others in the future who may have a similar question to yours.

Answer (score 1):

If the value in `A5` is the only value in the column `A1:A20` that is manually entered, and the rest of the values are calculated with formulas, wrap those formulas in `if()`, like this:

`=if(isblank(A5), iferror(1/0), "another value based on " & A5 & " and perhaps some other references")`

If the values in `A1:A20` are manually entered, you will need a script to clear them. Use an `onEdit(e)` [simple trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers), like this:

```
/**
* Simple trigger that runs each time the user hand edits the spreadsheet.
*
* @param {Object} e The onEdit() event object.
*/
function onEdit(e) {
  if (!e) {
    throw new Error(
      'Please do not run the onEdit(e) function in the script editor window. '
      + 'It runs automatically when you hand edit the spreadsheet. '
      + 'See https://stackoverflow.com/a/63851123/13045193.'
    );
  }
  let sheet;
  if (!e.value
    || e.range.rowStart !== 5
    || e.range.columnStart !== 1 // column A
    || (sheet = e.range.getSheet()).getName().match(/^(Sheet1|Sheet2|Sheet3)$/i)) {
    return;
  }
  sheet.getRangeList(['A1:A4', 'A6:A10']).clearContent();
}
```